# Sonarqube 6.7 - Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS, com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Having the below issue after upgrading to SonarQube 6.7. I'm using docker image for sonarqube, I just ran the migrations scripts just like suggested by Sonarquibe UI. 
Can someone suggest ?

Thank you

```
2018.05.15 06:58:42 INFO  ce[AWNimASHSOFQrk0D-LC8][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Execute task | project=myproject:develop | type=REPORT | id=AWNimASHSOFQrk0D-LC8 | submitter=jenkins
2018.05.15 06:59:52 ERROR ce[AWNimASHSOFQrk0D-LC8][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Failed to execute task AWNimASHSOFQrk0D-LC8
org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException: Visit of Component {key=myproject:develop,type=PROJECT} failed
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:74)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.ExecuteVisitorsStep.execute(ExecuteVisitorsStep.java:51)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:73)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:134)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:97)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.withCustomizedThreadName(CeWorkerImpl.java:81)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:73)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS [KEE=AV9aIkjMZ-jmCeoEg-IR]
The error may exist in org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper
The error may involve org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.scrollNonClosedByComponentUuid
The error occurred while handling results
SQL: select           i.id,     i.kee as kee,     i.rule_id as ruleId,     i.severity as severity,     i.manual_severity as manualSeverity,     i.message as message,     i.line as line,     i.locations as locations,     i.gap as gap,     i.effort as effort,     i.status as status,     i.resolution as resolution,     i.checksum as checksum,     i.assignee as assignee,     i.author_login as authorLogin,     i.tags as tagsString,     i.issue_attributes as issueAttributes,     i.issue_creation_date as issueCreationTime,     i.issue_update_date as issueUpdateTime,     i.issue_close_date as issueCloseTime,     i.created_at as createdAt,     i.updated_at as updatedAt,     r.plugin_rule_key as ruleKey,     r.plugin_name as ruleRepo,     r.language as language,     p.kee as componentKey,     i.component_uuid as componentUuid,     p.module_uuid as moduleUuid,     p.module_uuid_path as moduleUuidPath,     p.path as filePath,     root.kee as projectKey,     i.project_uuid as projectUuid,     i.issue_type as type         from issues i     inner join rules r on r.id=i.rule_id     inner join projects p on p.uuid=i.component_uuid     inner join projects root on root.uuid=i.project_uuid     where     i.component_uuid = ? and     i.status <> 'CLOSED'
Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS [KEE=AV9aIkjMZ-jmCeoEg-IR]
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:172)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:158)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeWithResultHandler(MapperMethod.java:126)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:72)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.scrollNonClosedByComponentUuid(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.issue.ComponentIssuesLoader.loadForComponentUuid(ComponentIssuesLoader.java:73)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.issue.ComponentIssuesLoader.loadForComponentUuid(ComponentIssuesLoader.java:51)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.issue.CloseIssuesOnRemovedComponentsVisitor.closeIssuesForDeletedComponentUuids(CloseIssuesOnRemovedComponentsVisitor.java:60)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.issue.CloseIssuesOnRemovedComponentsVisitor.visitProject(CloseIssuesOnRemovedComponentsVisitor.java:53)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.TypeAwareVisitorWrapper.visitProject(TypeAwareVisitorWrapper.java:47)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitNode(VisitorsCrawler.java:120)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:100)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS [KEE=AV9aIkjMZ-jmCeoEg-IR]
    at org.sonar.db.issue.IssueDto.parseLocations(IssueDto.java:652)
    at org.sonar.db.issue.IssueDto.toDefaultIssue(IssueDto.java:721)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.issue.ComponentIssuesLoader.lambda$loadForComponentUuid$1(ComponentIssuesLoader.java:74)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.callResultHandler(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:363)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.storeObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:356)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:348)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:322)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:298)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:192)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:170)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.truncatedMessage(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:70)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.refillBuffer(CodedInputStream.java:1068)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readRawByte(CodedInputStream.java:1135)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readRawVarint64SlowPath(CodedInputStream.java:778)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readRawVarint32(CodedInputStream.java:637)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readInt32(CodedInputStream.java:348)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbCommons$TextRange.<init>(DbCommons.java:149)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbCommons$TextRange.<init>(DbCommons.java:90)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbCommons$TextRange$1.parsePartialFrom(DbCommons.java:750)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbCommons$TextRange$1.parsePartialFrom(DbCommons.java:744)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:495)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations.<init>(DbIssues.java:99)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations.<init>(DbIssues.java:55)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations$1.parsePartialFrom(DbIssues.java:852)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations$1.parsePartialFrom(DbIssues.java:846)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:137)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:169)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:185)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations.parseFrom(DbIssues.java:253)
    at org.sonar.db.issue.IssueDto.parseLocations(IssueDto.java:650)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
2018.05.15 06:59:52 ERROR ce[AWNimASHSOFQrk0D-LC8][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Executed task | project=myproject:develop | type=REPORT | id=AWNimASHSOFQrk0D-LC8 | submitter=jenkins | time=70255ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved my problem executing this query on sonar schema. I guess that was definitely related to version upgrade... not a clean solution but still ok to me as I didn't need to have historical data

```
delete from issues where STATUS != "CLOSED"
```